# Counting all possible abstract simplicial complexes on a vertex set $[m]$

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics

Let $[m]=\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ and consider $2^{[m]}$ the power set on $[m]$. An abstract simplicial complex on $[m]$ is a subset $K\subset 2^{[m]} $ closed under the taking of subsets, that is if $\tau\in K$ then all subsets of $\tau$ are also elements of $K$. I want to list all possible $K$ for a given $m$,  do we know how many are there? For example when $m=3$, I think there are 16 possible $K$: 
$$K_0=\{\}$$
$$K_1=\{\emptyset\}$$
$$K_2=\{1\},\; K_3=\{2\}, \; K_4=\{3\}$$
$$K_{5}=\{1,2\},\; K_{6}=\{1,3\},\; K_{7}=\{2,3\}\;$$
$$K_{8}=\{1,2,3\}$$
$$K_9=\{1,2,(12)\},\; K_{10}=\{1,3,(13)\},\; K_{11}=\{2,3,(23)\}$$
$$K_{12}=\{1,2,3,(12),(13)\},\; K_{13}=\{1,2,3,(12),(23)\},\; K_{14}=\{1,2,3,(13),(23)\}$$
$$K_{15}=\{1,2,3,(12),(13),(23)\}$$
$$K_{16}=\{1,2,3,(12),(13),(23),(123)\}$$
$$K_{17}=\{1,2,3,(12)\}, \; K_{18}=\{1,2,3,(13)\}, \;K_{19}=\{1,2,3,(23)\}, \;$$

Comment: What about $\{1,2,3,(12)\}$ (and the variants thereof)?

Comment: [Dedekind number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number) might be what you're looking for, by the way.

Comment: yes i will add the other variants in the question above. Thanks.

Comment: The Dedekind number for $m=3$ is 20 so one abstract simplicial complex is missing in my list above. Can someone help me finding the missing one. Thank you very much !!

Comment: You're missing the trivial one: $K_0=\{\}$. Purely formally, all the $K_i$ you listed should contain $\emptyset$, since that's a subset of all sets so it needs to be present in all non-empty abstract simplical complexes.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the difference between $K_0=\{\}$ and $K_1=\{\emptyset\}$. $K_1$ is the emptyset element of $2^{[m]}$ while $K_0$ is the emptyset element of $2^{(2^{[m]})}$ is this correct?

Comment: The main difference is that $K_0$ is an empty set -- it can be viewed both as being an empty subset of $2^{[m]}$ and as an element of $2^{2^{[m]}}$. On the other hand, $K_1$ is an one-element subset of $2^{[m]}$; its sole member is the empty subset of $[m]$.